# Hermite's solution of the general quintic in terms of theta functions

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, special-functions, theta-functions

Can someone point me at or produce a translation or modern exposition of Hermite's solution of the general quintic in terms of theta functions? (the "before" and "after" steps are [on the mathworld page for the quintic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html), but I'm interested in Hermite/Kronecker's process/proof)

Comment: I'm currently far away from my library, but as I seem to recall [these](http://www.springerlink.com/content/978-0-8176-4836-7/) [two](http://books.google.com/books?id=fcp9IiZd3tQC) books tackle the solution of the quintic via modular/theta functions.

Answer (score 3):

David Mumford's three volumes of "lectures on theta..." or some similar title, published by Birkhauser c. 1980, give a good more-general context for using modular forms to solve algebraic equations of all degrees. He gives careful attributions, which at the moment I do not remember, and do not have those at home to look at.

Comment: I have the first volume, all digitally: /Tata Lectures on Theta/: the second contains Hiroshi Umemura's /Resolutions of Algebraic Equations by Theta Constants/.

Answer (score 1):

See Beyond The Quartic by R. Bruce King (Birhauser)