# Clarification of Abel-Ruffini theorem statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, solvable-groups

From what I've studied, Abel-Ruffini theorem states that we can't find all the roots of some polynomials with degree above 5, **using only radicals and arithmetic operations**.

How does it imply that we can't have a formula that involves some other mathematics thus allowing us to find all the roots of any polynomial?
Do abstract algebra and Galois theory have a role in this I'm not aware of?

Comment: It does not, actually. We can construct solutions of quintics using mathematical function, yes. Lame way to do this : $f(a)$ where $f(x)$ is defined to be the inverse function of $x^5 + x$. This is the "so-called" bring radical. Smart way to do this : Elliptic functions. Explicitly given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't imply there isn't some other formula. Hermite, for example, found a solution for the general quintic using theta functions.

Comment: Could you explain better?

Comment: Not much, I'm afraid. I don't actually know *how* it was done, only that it was. Wikipedia has something here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical. There are some sources linked in this discussion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32616/hermites-solution-of-the-general-quintic-in-terms-of-theta-functions

Comment: Probably It would be too complex for me to understand it now. Thank you!